# Adding total N's f variable to tbl_regression using gtsummary package

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am trying to add a column that has total number of observations in each variable in my `tbl_regression` table. In `tbl_summary`, the function `add_n()` allows you to do this. However, in `tbl_regession` this option is not straight forward.

I have tried to do this by including N argument in the `modify_header` function in `tbl_regression`, but here the issue is that the levels within the variables have the N's of the variable as well. For example, using the code below, the *Species* variable has 150 observations and all of the levels of *Species* have N's equal to 150 (see image below). Is there any way of having N's for the *Species* variable but not for the levels? Any help is kindly appreciated.

```
# load packages
library(gtsummary)
theme_gtsummary_compact()

# build model
mod <- lm(Petal.Width ~ Species + Petal.Length, data = iris) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE) %>%
  modify_header(update = list(
  estimate ~ '**Coefficient**',
  ci~ '**95% CI**',
  N ~ '**N**'
))

mod
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `add_n()` function includes the number of observations from the model, and can also report the Ns within a categorical variable. Here are a few examples. All examples are printed with kable instead of gt to accurately appear in the reprex.

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.4.0'

# build model
tbl <- 
  lm(Petal.Width ~ Species + Petal.Length, data = iris) %>%
  tbl_regression() %>%
  bold_labels()

# add N to the header
tbl %>%
  modify_header(update = label ~ "**Characteristic (N = {n})**") %>%
  as_kable()
```

| **Characteristic (N = 150)** | **Beta** | **95% CI** | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Species** |  |  |  |
| setosa |  |  |  |
| versicolor | 0.44 | 0.23, 0.64 | <0.001 |
| virginica | 0.84 | 0.55, 1.1 | <0.001 |
| **Petal.Length** | 0.23 | 0.16, 0.30 | <0.001 |

```r
# add N to variable label rows
tbl %>%
  add_n() %>%
  as_kable()
```

| **Characteristic** | **N** | **Beta** | **95% CI** | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Species** | 150 |  |  |  |
| setosa |  |  |  |  |
| versicolor |  | 0.44 | 0.23, 0.64 | <0.001 |
| virginica |  | 0.84 | 0.55, 1.1 | <0.001 |
| **Petal.Length** | 150 | 0.23 | 0.16, 0.30 | <0.001 |

```r
# add N to variable label and level rows
tbl %>%
  add_n(location = "level") %>%
  as_kable()
```

| **Characteristic** | **N** | **Beta** | **95% CI** | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Species** |  |  |  |  |
| setosa | 50 |  |  |  |
| versicolor | 50 | 0.44 | 0.23, 0.64 | <0.001 |
| virginica | 50 | 0.84 | 0.55, 1.1 | <0.001 |
| **Petal.Length** | 150 | 0.23 | 0.16, 0.30 | <0.001 |

<sup>Created on 2021-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clean. I am after the opposite, have the total N's for the variable and not for the levels. An equivalent of add_n() function for tbl_regression.

Comment: In a multivariable regression model, all of the total Ns are always the same for each variable, e.g. there are 150 observations of Species, there are 150 observations of Petal.Length.

Comment: What if I was to stack few different models on top of each other, how would that work?!

Comment: In that case, you can typically get what you need using `tbl_uvregression()`. If you feel you need `tbl_regression()`, you can also add the following line to your example code in the original post: `mod$table_body <- mod$table_body %>% mutate(N = ifelse(row_type == "label", N, NA))`

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg As a follow-up, I would like to ask if it is possible to add the total number of censored observations to the regression table. Thank you!

Comment: There is an example like this here. Note, you'll need the dev version of the package for this to work. http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/dev/reference/modify_table_body.html

Comment: This is wonderful! I downloaded the dev version instead but notice that for reference levels, question marks inside of diamonds are displayed. Is there a way to use dash instead?

Comment: Actually when I knit the markdown files, question marks inside of diamonds are turned to dashes automatically. Thanks for this package!

Comment: Glad it's working...I've never seen diamonds and question marks in the output before